# In R when using formattable() place line breaks between entries inside a single cell

Tags: r

I'm using formattable() from the package formattable in R.
Here's some code that produces a table with the issue I want to get around.

```
a1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
data <- c(100, 155, -4)
a2 <- c(0, paste(data, collapse = "; "), 1000000) 
b <- data.frame(cbind(a1, a2))
                
formattable(b)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

What I want is for the cell with the three entries to have each value on a new line, so it looks like so:

[image]

If it looked like this I could remove the semicolons. I made the second image by shrinking my window, but I want the data to always look this way no matter how big the user's window is. Is there a way in formattable() or elsewhere where this can be forced?

Note that I have tried the following in the paste() function and it did not work.

```
paste(data, collapse = "; \n")
```

Comment: I think it depends on the display size, try to mess up with rstudio window viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collapsing using `"<br> "` seems to do the trick (note the extra space is necessary):

```
a1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
data <- c(100, 155, -4)
a2 <- c(0, paste(data, collapse = "<br> "), 1000000) 
b <- data.frame(cbind(a1, a2))
width <- 10

formattable(b)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I saw <br> as html code when looking for a solution, but didn't bother to try it since I didn't think it would work. Lesson learned, I should try everything anyways haha.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used `formatable`. I wonder if `kableExtra` is helpful here.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(a1 = c(1, 2, 2,2, 3),
                 a2 = c(0, 100, 155, -4, 1000000)) 
kable(df) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1:2, valign = "top")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It looks pretty good, but the issue comes if in a later column I then want just the three rows again.

```
df <- data.frame(a1 = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3),
                 a2 = c(0, 100, 155, -4, 1000000),
                 a3 = c(0, 100, 155, -4, 1000000),
                 a4 = c(1,6,6,6,3)) 
```
If you run this df through the kable code, the 4th column is 1,6,6,6,3 instead of just 1,6,3.