# Combine text from two or more cells into one cell in formattable R

Tags: r, formattable

Given a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(class = c("A", "", "", "B", ""), name = c("Jack", 
"Rose", "Steve", "James", "Rick"), score = c(7L, 18L, 9L, 15L, 
12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Is it possible I get the output effect as follows with formattable:

[image]

```
library(df)
formattable(df)
```

Out:

[image]

Updated code:

```
library(flextable)

data <- flextable(
  df, 
  col_keys = c("class", "name", "score"))
data <- merge_v(data, j = c("class"))
formattable(data)
```

Out:

```
Error in create_obj(x, "formattable", list(formatter = formatter, format = list(...), : 
argument "formatter" is missing, with no default
```

It raises same error as above:

```
library(gt)

# dummy data
dat <- tibble(
  a=1:3,
  b=c("a","b c","d e f")
)

d <- dat %>% 
  mutate(b = str_replace_all(b, " ", "<br>")) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_markdown(columns = TRUE)

formattable(d)
```

Code which may help:

```
a1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
data <- c(100, 155, -4)
a2 <- c(0, paste(data, collapse = "<br> "), 1000000) 
b <- data.frame(cbind(a1, a2))
width <- 10

formattable(b)
```

Out:

[image]

Reference:

[In R when using formattable() place line breaks between entries inside a single cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62766921/in-r-when-using-formattable-place-line-breaks-between-entries-inside-a-single)

Comment: I like to use `flextable` for that. Should you not easily find a `formattable` solution see https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2020-01-11/web/packages/flextable/vignettes/overview.html

Comment: I try to use `merge_v` from `flextable` then use `formattable`, seems not working.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63354827/680068

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use `formattable` or apply it to data after merged using other packes since the major part of my code is realized with `formattable` . Is it possible?